# etree & xpath return entire html instead of text

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml

I'm working around since quite a while on this and tried all kind of namespace solutions. However, my current script is not printing the demanded strings but the entire html dump. Does anyone knows how to get around that issue?

```py
from lxml.html import parse
from lxml import etree
import requests

r = requests.get('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Aachener-Strasse-10713-Berlin.html')
tree = etree.parse(r.text)
NSMAP = {'mw':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/'}
Name2 = tree.xpath('//{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
Name3 = tree.find("//html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")
print(Name2, Name3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are inherited. If a document is XHTML, then all the nodes in the document are in the XHTML namespace by default.

That means you must use that namespace in every step of your XPath expression. Using it on the first step (`html`) is not enough.

`nsmap` can help you with keeping the code manageable, but you have to use it, too.

```
from lxml.html import parse
import requests
from lxml import etree

r = requests.get('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Aachener-Strasse-10713-Berlin.html')
tree = etree.parse(r.text)
nsmap = {'x':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/'}

path = '//x:body/x:div[7]/x:div/x:div/x:div/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[2]/x:a'
name = tree.findall(path, nsmap)
```

The above is unwieldy and brittle. Try to create a simpler expression.

Rule: Never use XPath that was automatically generated. Manually create the "least specific" expression (i.e. least dependent on irrelevant document structure, like `div` nesting levels or -positions) that still matches exactly what you need. Maybe along the lines of this.

```
name = tree.findall('//x:table[@class="foo"]//x:td[2]/x:a', nsmap)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help and indeed simpler expressions would be needed here. However, with this code I get the following error: `File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse(r.text)`...`IOError: <exception str() failed>` I don't really find any similar errors on stackoverflow.

Comment: No idea. For me this errors at `tree = etree.parse(r.text)`, which is a line that I have not even touched. My changes are in the last two lines only, so you should actually see the same error in your own code.

Comment: Before it would have dumped the whole html file because I had the following lines in the code above `import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('iso-8859-1')` strange... what could be wrong with that line? I thought it makes sense to convert the html into a string in order to parse it after... If I put `tree = etree.parse(r)` I get `TypeError: cannot parse from 'Response'`

Comment: But `r.text` already is a string, so there is no need for any gymnastics. Maybe the source code of the website is invalid XHTML (seems like it) which might cause the ETree XML parser to barf. Try their method of parsing (potentially) broken HTML as documented here http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. The HTML parser also strips the XHTML namespace for you, so that you can write plain regular XPath.

Comment: could you paste the code that worked out for you? Because in my case I have this code: `r = requests.get('https://berlin.kauperts.de/Strassen/Aachener-Strasse-10713-Berlin.html')
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(r), parser)
result = etree.tostring(tree.getroot(),
                        pretty_print=True, method="html")
print(result)
nsmap = {'x':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/'}
#/html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/h1
path = './/x:body/x:div[7]/x:div/x:div/x:div/x:h1'
name = tree.findall(path, nsmap)
print(name)` and my result is empty: `[]`

Comment: I said you can drop the namespaces and write plain regular XPath. ;)

Comment: lol... thank you very much for your help. but I still get an empty value and I have no clue why! `name = tree.xpath('//html/body/div[7]/div/div/div/h1[@class="title"]/value')`

Comment: Debug your XPath expression. Make it simpler. `tree.xpath('//a')` gives a result for me, which means it works, which means your XPath is wrong. You will find the mistake, I'm sure.